# Obtaining data key/value pair from Materialise CSS autocomplete. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was able to change the code below to output what I click to console. As you can see, the sendItem function does that for me.

I am having a hard time accomplishing the following:

1. User types AP
2. autocomplete completes it to Apple
3. User clicks on APPLE
4. **Its corresponding value is sent to console**

Basically, materialize has a really awesome function they choose to display pictures with, when it can do a lot more. For example, a whole mySQL search based on:

1. Load the auto complete data with current pending clients
2. Each client is a key/value pair in a json array of clients (array of
   arrays)
3. autocomplete searches the keys in the data array and upon user
   click,
4. dispatches a ajax mysql search for its corresponding value which in
   this case is a unique client id.
5. Finally, we render the results to user.

```js
function sendItem(val) {
    console.log(val);
}

$(function () {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "Microsoft": null,
            "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
        onAutocomplete: function(txt) {
          sendItem(txt);
        },
        limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
                <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is no documentation about this in the plugin. So, one solution would be performing the search yourself based in the selected value (`txt` parameter of `onAutocomplete` function).

So, keep a data structure that maps the keys and values, similar to the `data` option passed to the plugin, and once a value is selected, you use it to find the corresponding value in your data structure and perform the operations you want.

Good luck.

**Update**

Now they material css providing documentation for the autocomplete but this is available for the version 1.0.0-rc.2 and to view the documentation 
[click here](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html)

Comment: Yeah. I believe with your feedback, the keywords I should be searching on Google are jquery ajax live search. Shouldn't be hard to find at all. In the mean time, I was able to research a solution and posted it as an answer. I wonder which should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Well... would you guys say this solution is a.. **bit of a hack**? Because... for some reason, it just doesn't please the eye for me.

Perhaps I should just wait for their framework to evolve a bit more and just go learn how to create an ajax live search from scratch which shouldn't be hard to find on Google.

```js
function sendItem_OLD(val) {
    console.log(val);
}

function sendItem(ele, e) {
    if (e.isTrigger != undefined) {
        console.log('Key: ' + ele.value + ' | Value: ' + $(ele).nextAll('.dropdown-content').find('img').attr('src'));
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Apple": null,
            "John Doe": "465605",
            "Google": "http://placehold.it/250x250"
        },
        limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" onchange="sendItem(this, event)">
                <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```